# Google Cloud SQL tracking long queries

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have an existing MySQL (version 5.7) instance hosted (managed) by Google Cloud SQL. I have spikes on the CPU consumption and want to investigate the reasons why.

By using this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/stackdriver-monitor-slow-query-mysql), I found that it's possible via a few database flags.

Changed the database flags configuration to this:

[image]

I waited two hours to see the logs in the Stackdrive but nothing there. So, I wonder if it because the `long_query_time` that was initially equal to 5. I changed it to zero - should track any query. But same here - nothing on the Stackdrive logs.

Screenshot my Stackdrive - nothing related to long query tracking:
[image]

What is the reason? What do I need to fix?

Comment: I tried the guide that you shared, for me is working as is expected (I have created an instance from the scratch)

is your instance patched ?

`gcloud sql instances patch cloudsql001 --database-flags=log_output='FILE',slow_query_log=on,long_query_time=2
`

Comment: I used the GCP website to make this change since the `gcloud` command said that restart might be required... Since it's production database I wasn't accepted this. While making it on the GCP control panel - restart wasn't needed...

Answer (score 0):

For an existent database is necessary patch the instance running this command:

```
gcloud sql instances patch cloudsql001 --database-flags=log_output='FILE',slow_query_log=on,long_query_time=2
```

Is mandatory restart in order to enable the slow query log (not matter if you are using the web ui since in the backend run the same commands that GCloud SDK), maybe you can perform it in the next maintenance window for your system.

Keep in mind that enable slow query logs cause a performance degradation and it is not recommended for a long time in production environment.